# How to conect database in user model file

Tags: php

Now I want to finally move on and use classes. But I can't figure out a proper way to have access to mysql in functions of my classes without inclusion of the so called db.php file on top of each file.

db.php

```
class ConnectionDB{

    private $server = "localhost";
    private $username = "root";
    private $password = "";
    private $db = "oop_crud";
    private $conn;

    public function __construct(){
        try{
            $this->conn = new mysqli($this->server, $this->username,$this->password,$this->db);
        }
        catch (Exception $e){
            echo "Connection faild" .$e->getMessage();
        }
    }

}
```

Usermodel.php

```
    include 'db.php';
    $ConnectionDB = new ConnectionDB();
    class usermodel {

        public function insert()
        {
            if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
                $name = $_POST['name'];
                $mobile = $_POST['mobile'];
                $email = $_POST['email'];
                $password = $_POST['password'];
                if ((!empty($name)) && (!empty($email)) && (!empty($mobile)) && (!empty($password))) {
                    $data = "INSERT INTO `register` (`u_id` , `name`, `mobile`,`email`,`password`) VALUES (NULL , '$name', '$mobile' , '$email', '$password')";
                    if ($sql = $this->conn->query($data)) {
                        echo "Yes";
                    }else{
                        echo "No";
                    }
                }else{
                        echo    '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button><strong>Danger!</strong> All Field are Required </div>';
                }
            }
        }
    }


 ?>
```

i want to call ConnectionDB class in my usermodel file

Comment: Think Variable Scope. Your $conn is not part of the `usermodel` object as you made the connections outside the class

Comment: This code is anything but classes. Rather, it's just a procedural code in disguise. in the object code there shouldnt be `echo "Connection faild" .$e->getMessage();` shouldnt be `if ((!empty($name))` etc. `echo "Yes";`, shouldn't be `echo  '<div class="`. and if you need database connection you need to pass it via constructor

Answer (score -1):

What you should do is to think about an implementation of psr-4 autoloading. Please read more about this here: [PSR-4](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/)

The easiest way to autoload classes is to use composer and `composer init` command in your project: [Composer Installation](https://getcomposer.org/download/)

Once you run this command it will guide you through a few steps. Please choose "project" as a type and follow the instructions.

Then include autoload.php file from vendor/autoload.php in your index.php file and voila - if you follow psr-4 rules then all the classes will be loaded automatically without a need to use `include 'db.php';` or similar code.

Comment: This has nothing to do with a class not being loaded, its to do with Scope. `$this->conn` does not exist in `usermodel` and even if the classes were loaded automatically that property would still not exist in `usermodel`

Comment: Bartosz Brożek This is PHP

Comment: autoloading doesn't help with resources and the db connection being one

Comment: My answer concerned this part of the question: "But I can't figure out a proper way to have access to mysql in functions of my classes without inclusion of the so called db.php file on top of each file." - I believe author asked about automatically including class files, once a new object of certain class is instantiated. But if the author wants to use database connection in his "usermodel" class he needs to use Dependency Injection to inject one object (db connection) into another, which depends on it (usermodel).